# React Redux and Context api together

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-context

I have a question which I am unable to find proper resource to clarify my mind around this. Basically the scenario is I am using Redux store to retrieve some data where that data will be used in couple of different components so I decided to create a Context Api which connects to Redux store and use that context in the components itself.

The question is let's say I have 2 components A and B where A is the parent, would it be more efficient to use context in parent (A) and pass the data as props to the child, or it wouldn't make any difference if I use context in both A and B so I need to pass less props to child component (B).

The real scenario is a bit more complex than this but just curious about if creating the Context connected to Redux store many times has any drawbacks over props drilling.

Comment: Not even sure how mixing Context and Redux at the same time could improve your application in any way. Just stick with one of them. I would not say that using props has any significant performance improvements over redux, but think a little bit over dependencies, it really makes sense to depends on the redux store to hold your component data ?

Comment: So basically by using Context and Redux together, I map "state" and "dispatch" only once in the Context and then I will directly use the state and dispatch easily in every component saving me from the hassle of "connecting" my component for mapping those. @Luillyfe

Comment: Connect is using Context behind the scenes.

Comment: Yes but as I said, I don't need to deal with the mapping for each of my components if I do it once in the Context and use the hook of context instead.

Comment: But every component (using that context) will has access to all the state in your redux store. Is that ok to you ?

Comment: Not if I destructure the data that I want to use only. For example, if I have X,Y,Z available in my context and I want to use only X in my component then I will just do it like;
let {X} = useMyContext();

But yes I will have access to every data provided by the context in that component, do you think that would make any performance issues?

Comment: How that will be different from mapping in the connect function? because in that case you have to do it in every component.

Comment: For the connect function I should provide the states and the actions I want to connect which clutters the component. That's what I meant it would be easier to do all those mappings in the context and use the context in a single line for my components which would make it more readable than connecting. Theoretically, there is no difference, just much cleaner to read and work with.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is mostly a matter of preference. Here's what I would consider when making this decision:

1. How many props will be passed to the child? If it's just a few, then I'll use 1 context provider on the parent and use prop drilling.
2. How many props will be shared between parent and child? Maybe I have props that are only needed in the parent, or vice versa. If that's the case then I would use a context provider for each component, and only pull in those props that I need for each one.

Overall I lean towards prop drilling in a case like you've described, but there are certainly reasons why you might want to consider separate context providers for your components.

Comment: The main reason of the question is, I have UI related stuff like "loading", "errors" etc. where they are both needed in the parent and child and in some situations child of the child. So it ends up passing too many props to each child so I was curious rather than passing too many props, is there any drawback using the Context in each of them separately, like is it going to slow down the component rendering process by any means or the context is "setup" only once no matter how many times you use it? That's the main question.